# Concatenate range except for certain cells

Tags: excel, vba

I'm trying to concatenate values in a row with ", " as my separator. I want all values except for specific text. In this case, concatenate range except for "Yes", "No", "N/A", and blanks.

Comment: VBA? You could probably do this with TEXTJOIN.

Comment: If you have suggestions, I'm open!

Comment: Look into `IF` and `TEXTJOIN` Excel functions. No need for any VBA to do this. Consider [edit]ing your post to include some sample data, what you've tried, and how it's failing.

Answer (score 0):

You could also go the following route:
first Concatenate everything, and then 
SUBSTITUTE the unwanted texts ["No"|"Yes"|"N/A"] with "" (empty character). Do not forget to get rid of potential commas at string start in case you have a Yes|No|N/A at the beginning of your Concatenated string. The cases where the unwanted text is right in the middle of the string body is a Subtitution of double Commas ",,"

Answer (score 0):

I actually found a solution that works from http://www.eileenslounge.com/viewtopic.php?f=27&t=12298#. It's basically a Concatenateifs with multiple criteria. I used the vba that used syntaxes. Worked like a charm!